# Vim powerline with broken encoding

Tags: vim, gnome-terminal, character-encoding, vimrc, powerline

I trying to learn using vim, I am enjoining a lot, but I copied the vimrc from github and I would like to understand what is causing the break of powerline encoding.

.[image: Snapshot of my vim]

1. In the vimrc file I have: `set encoding=utf-8`
2. I cleared the PowerLine cache
3. My vim version doesn't show the `--with-features=big`   flag.

Could this be the problem and if yes, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you want to check that your terminal has Unicode enabled. According to [Ubuntu's locale help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#Changing_settings_permanently), you should edit the file `/etc/default/locale` to have this content:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

(replace `en_US` with your language, of course), and then run:

```
sudo locale-gen
```

You may need to log out and log in again. Test by executing this (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12649896/168034)):

```
$ echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"
```

The output should be ☠.

Secondly, Powerline uses a few [special glyphs in the Unicode Private Use Area](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fontpatching.html#glyph-table), so you should read [the docs on Fontconfig](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/linux.html?highlight=fontconfig#fontconfig). The font installation requires 2 main steps:

1. Put the font file `PowerlineSymbols.otf` in `~/.fonts/` (or another X font directory)
2. Put the font config file `10-powerline-symbols.conf` in either `~/.fonts.conf.d/` or `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/`, depending on your fontconfig version (`~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/` is newer, but I'm not sure since when it's available)